# How Do I drive a objects local position?

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers

I have a knee joint, when it bends, I need a empty to move in and out on a local axis based on the value of the local rotation of the knee.

in blender game with polling it would look like this

Empty.worldPosition = Empty.parent.worldWorldPosition+(Empty.parent.worldOrienation.col[1]*(variable based on local Rot))

How can I do the same with a driver so I don't need to Poll angles?

Comment: Did you try using a the 'Rotational Difference' driver option?

Comment: The variable I need is known, the setting of the local position using a driver is not*

Comment: Empty.worldPosition = Empty.parent.worldWorldPosition+(Empty.parent.worldOrientation.col[1]*(variable based on local Rot))

is the part I don't know how to do with a driver*

Comment: (*Set the local position based on the variable collected)

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41736 here is a test file

I know I can use a IK stretch to constraint, but I have some cyclic dependencies when using 2 hydraulics connecting at a unknown point in space *

Comment: Hence the need for a driver on at least 1 side of the hydraulic

Comment: Feel free to post answer to your own question :)